# Running Cruise Control .NET as a Service

Tags: svn, configuration, cruisecontrol.net

I've been configuring and testing CCNet for a little while now using Virtual PC to host it. Everything went well and it was decided to transfer the configuration to a server location - which went as well as could be expected. A few tweaks and kicks and i had it running as before.

The problem is that we now need to run CCNet as a service which is proving problematic.

I have configured a domain level user with the same access rights as myself (after all, the console application has been running as me for about 3 months now) and configured the service to run under that user.

I started the service and it hung! [I'll not bore you with the details of forcing the service to stop and closing the sockets that were held open]. When I was eventually able to run the console again I did a 'Run As' and entered the 'cruisecontrol' user details, click OK and saw that there was a problem accessing SVN via https. I've sorted that by running IE as 'cruisecontrol', navigating to the repository and accepting/installing the certificate.
Next when I ran the console application as 'cruisecontrol' it hangs after the following lines:

`2009-01-15 16:55:50,994 [Pepsi Webservices:DEBUG] Running Subversion with arguments : log --xml --limit 1 https://ash-dev-005.[path to trunk]`

2009-01-15 16:55:51,478 [Pepsi Webservices:DEBUG] Authentication realm: https://ash-dev-005.[path to repository] Subversion Repositories

After it times out I can close the console, run it as normal (i.e. as me) and it runs fine. I have tried logging into the server as the 'cruisecontrol' user and tried running the console but with the same result.

Now, heres the thing: This morning I logged into the server as the 'cruisecontrol' user and opened a command window. I navigated to the trunk of my project and typed 'svn update' and was prompted for a password.

This is not surprising but the line above that prompt was the 'Authentication realm:...' line above! Looking at the log file, sure enough right after the process is killed by CCNet there is a prompt for a password. Is CCNet/SVN waiting for a password entry and then timing out? If so, why it is not using the one in the config file?

I entered the password and the update proceeded without any problems (so the cruisecontrol user does have permissions to access the repository from the server). I entered the command again and was not prompted a second time so i tried opening a new command window and rerunning the command - still not prompted for a password so i logged out and back in (as cruisecontrol) and tried again but was still not prompted.

The good news is that when I run the console application as the cruisecontrol user (whether logged in as cruisecontrol or just using Run As) everything appears to be OK.

So what's my question? 
    Well, why is CCNet not using the password in the config file?
    How has entering the password in the command prompt resolved the problem (and will it persist)?

Any suggestions/insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm - I may have answered my own question here (or not, only time will tell).

For some reason CCNet does not appear to be using the credential in the config file (don't know why). When it calls SVN it waits for a password to be entered, even if the user cannot see it, and then times out when it doesn't get one.

By accessing SVN from the command line the password prompt is visible and can be entered, moreover the password is cached in %app_data%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple inside an encrypted file for that user. This is why subsequent commands do not prompt for a password and why the console application will run without any problems.

I'm going to configure the CCService now so hopefully this will work as well as the console application does now.

If you have had any similar experiences please let me know. In the meantime I may raise the issue with ThoughtWorks.

Comment: Issues like this are better raised in the Google User Groups or Developer groups, unless you have a reproducable issue. In which case you could log an issue in JIRA on the ThoughtWorks site

Comment: There is something wrong in your configuration.  We've been using CC.Net for years and I can guarantee that it does use the username and password in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember, when you run cc.net as a service, it uses another config file then when you run it as a console app.
(ccservice.exe.config instead of cc.exe.config).

Comment: True enough but when I ran the console or service as me then I had no problems. I'm not sure why I had to cache the password manually and why CCNet doesn't use the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Related to Frederik's response - On our server, we specify the subversion credentials in the project itself.  The sourcecontrol block for one of these projects would look something like this:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
    <trunkUrl>http://myserver/svn/myproject/trunk</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>C:\source\MyProject</workingDirectory>
    <username>foo</username>
    <password>bar</password>
    <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Comment: I have a similar configuration, i.e. I specified the username and password for svn, but ccnet appears to be ignoring this. I've got this working for now but will try to repsoduce it on a VM when I get five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,
It is pretty easy to diagnose if CruiseControl is using the password in the config file or not as you will see the command line in the log and the actual password parameter and password if it is being used, and passed to svn. If you have the password and user in the configuration file and they are not being passed, the first thing I would check is that your configuration file is valid and the config file in the file system is what is actually being used. If you make an invalid change to the configuration file, CC.NET just ignores it as long as the service is running and just keeps using the version it has cached internally without any warnings or messages. So again the only way to verify is to look at the config through the web dashboard and make sure it reflects what you expect, or you could bounce the service at which point it will stop and point out your error. In the end though you can work around this as you did though by caching the password with subversion.

Comment: My logs didn't have any command lines for the password, just the username. I did try restarting the service to see if it would complain about something but it never did. Thanks anyway.