# Pass arguments to svn when using CruiseControl.net

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I would like to pass arguments to SVN while I'm using CruiseControl.net. I have the following sourcecontrol block in my ccnet.config file:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn" username="username" password="password">
    <trunkUrl>https://www.example.com/blah/blah/blah</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>C:\Subversion\blah\</workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Is there anyway that I can alter the sourcecontrol block so that is passes some arguments to svn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found my own answer. Apparently the only way I could figure out how to do this was to alter my sourcecontrol block by adding the executable argument with a batch file I wrote like so:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn" username="username" password="password" executable="C:\Subversion\blah\mysvn.bat">
    <trunkUrl>https://www.example.com/blah/blah/blah</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>C:\Subversion\blah\</workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

and then in mysvn.bat I have:

```
svn %* --trust-server-cert
```

where `--trust-server-cert` is the argument I wanted to add